# Use optional dependency in module only if main project implements it

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies, build-system

I'm using Gradle 3.0 with Android. I got module A, that acts as a library (Android library, to be precise).

I would like to have module A implement a dependency and use it *if and only if* the main project includes that dependency as well.

If it doesn't, the library should just bypass the use of that optional dependency.

So, if I have dependency X that returns a string.

And module A that is implemented in the main project.

I'd like module A to access the symbols of dependency X during compile time and only use it if the main project includes dependency X as a dependency in its own `build.gradle` file.

I looked into `compileOnly` keyword but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: I think that this is not a good idea. Your library will be coupled to a dependency defined in the master project. I think that you should define an interface that your library expects and keep your library decoupled.

Comment: I am not in control of the master project, so I can't force any dependency I can. I have to expect that "If the dependency is there, do stuff with it. Else, forget about it"

Comment: @Solidak did you managed to find a way? Need same functionality